# python settings for a project - circular imports / dependency injection

Tags: python, dependency-injection, settings, python-import

I've created a 'Django style' settings files for different environments.
The settings files define some variables, and also serves as dependency injection for other modules.

So the structure is:

```
settings/
    ___init__.py
    base.py
    dev.py
    dev2.py
    prod.py

service/
    __init__.py
    service.py
    service_mock.py
```

And in `settings/__init__.py` I write:

```
settings_env = os.environ.get('PROJECT_SETTINGS', '')
if settings_env == 'prod':
   from .prod import *
elif settings_env == 'dev':
   from .dev import *
```

Each settings file define different some variables, and also import a class from `service.py` or `service_mock.py`, depends on the environment variable.
This works mostly fine.

Now, the problem is that the `service.py` cannot import the settings package, because the settings files import the `service.py`, so that will become a circular import.

As I see in Django it is solved by using import strings in the settings files, instead of actual imports.
I don't really like the idea as I lose some of the IDE autocomplete features, also I'm not sure how to actually create the settings object that Django provides.

What are the solutions to this problem? Having a settings file that serves as a dependency injection container that imports modules, and get imported by the same modules?  Preferably a simple solution.

Answer (score 5):

A very common, and certainly easiest solution to circular imports, is to defer imports until you actually need them. For example, change

```
import settings
def func():
    settings.things
```

to

```
def func():
    import settings
    settings.things
```

If you absolutely must have module-global imports, there are various tricks you could use, such as

```
settings = None
def import_stuff():
    global settings
    import settings as s
    settings = s
```

or have a class

```
class Settings():
    mod = None        

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if self.mod is None:
            import settings
            self.mod = settings
        return getattr(self.mod, attr)

settings = Settings()
```

(or generalise for any module name)

Comment: Thanks. What's the point with the __getattr__ if? wouldn't it be ok to import settings on every getattr access? Is this considered a good pattern to import like that? is there are better patterns, like using an ini file? I would actually prefer an ini file, but then I lose the capabilities of python code

Comment: No, you would only use  pattern like this is absolutely necessary, and others would consider it hacky. You could import every time at a small performance cost. I forgot to say: the *best* thing would, of course, be to factor out the things you need imported in both places into a separate module that depends on neither!

Comment: Can you explain how? everything in the code need to import the settings. but the settings import the service or the mock service for other modules. Or, how can I use an ini/text file and still get the benefits of python code (like creating a class instance)?

Comment: Refactoring I think is beyond what can be shown here, sorry. Perhaps if you started another question with some specifics of your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
settings_env = os.environ.get('PROJECT_SETTINGS', '')
if settings_env == 'prod':
   from .prod import *
elif settings_env == 'dev':
   from .dev import *
```

you can just export a variable:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE your_project.settings.dev2
```

and Django will read the right file.

Also:
Instead of

```
import settings
```

you'd like to use:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

and above can be nested in methods/functions to avoid circular imports.

see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code

see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#custom-default-settings

Comment: My project is not django, I try to implement django style settings